# Python, Capture image after countdown ends using webcam

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv

i want my program to capture image after countdown ends. But during the countdown, i want it to show me the live cam. This is my code.

```
import cv2
import time
cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
countdown=3
img_counter = 0
cv2.namedWindow("test")
ret, frame = cam.read()
cv2.imshow("test", frame)
img_name = "example.png"

while countdown >0:
                time.sleep(1)
                print(countdown)
                countdown -=1
                if countdown == 0:
                    cv2.imwrite(img_name, frame)
                    print("{} written!".format(img_name))

cam.release()

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Thanks but i need to see what the cam is showing before taking the picture.

Comment: What is the problem with your code? Where is the exception? Why did you post it here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is the waitKey function. It holds execution of your code for the number of **milliseconds** specified in the argument. So if you want to wait for 3 seconds, you can decrement in milliseconds instead of seconds, as shown below:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
seconds = 3

millis = seconds * 1000
while (millis > 0):
   # Capture frame-by-frame
   ret, frame = cap.read()
   millis = millis - 10
  # Display the resulting frame
   cv2.imshow('video recording', frame)

   if cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
       #this method holds execution for 10 milliseconds, which is why we 
       #reduce millis by 10
       break

 #once the while loop breaks, write img
img_name = "example.png"
cv2.imwrite(img_name, frame)
print("{} written!".format(img_name))
```